# Saving email as file in mutt?

Tags: mutt

When I press `S` in mutt, it saves the mail to a mail folder format (`cur/ tmp/ new/`), but I want a single file to be saved, just like how attachments are saved.

Is that configurable?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The actual message shows up as an attachment as well, so you can save it from the attachment list. From either the index or the message itself, hit <kbd>v</kbd> to open the attachments and <kbd>s</kbd> to save

Comment: Just a note: if your email message contains attachments, then saving just the first entry from the attachments list will save the message - but without the attachments included inside.

Comment: Another note: this doesn't save any headers, including sender, recipient and subject.

Comment: @Sparhawk It does save the headers but you have to press `h` to show them, first...

Comment: @m4110c That doesn't seem to work for me. In addition, I can always see some headers, and `h` just shows *all* the headers. Either way, the headers aren't saved.

Comment: @Sparhawk You're right, my bad. I just tested it and the headers are not saved this way. I guess the best way would be to go with the `|`  key and use a linux command to store the mail, as described in the answer of Kai von Fintel. Also setting the `set pipe_decode=yes`should not be omitted in the .muttrc

Answer (score 38):

The `s` command saves to a mailbox, which for you is in maildir format. Unfortunately, there is no save-to-file command, perhaps because in the historical mbox format, a mailbox that contains a single mail is just a file containing that mail.

The `mutt` command pipe-message (default shortcut `|`) can be used for this. It opens a command line and you write `cat > DESIRED-FILE-PATH`.

The "pipe-decode" option controls what happens to headers and mime parts when you save a message this way.

One could probably write a macro for this functionality.

Comment: Cool, this can save the headers as well, but for now, I'd use Michael's way, thanks!

Comment: This works well and provides an efficient manner of saving 50+ emails (using pattern-matching tagging) to file. I had to dig a little to find that by adding `set pipe_decode=yes` to my muttrc was what Kai von Fintel was writing about.

Comment: also, this saves the attachments in the exported email file, as well.

Comment: this is fine, but i see un-processed line breaks with `=` doing this.

Comment: Awesome. This worked great for me. I just wanted to extract some 20+ emails from an obsolete Maildir. Cheers!

Answer (score 13):

If you `touch` a file and then try to save or copy a message to it mutt will use it as a mbox.

Also you might want to use copy instead of save. Mutt assumes that a mail should only exist in one copy and saving a message to another mailbox will delete it from the first one, while copying will do a proper copy.

Comment: I needed to get the message with the full headers to paste it into a filter test script, and this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

[Kai von Fintel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30072/kai-von-fintel)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60891/18887) works perfectly, but I just thought I'd share a macro to streamline this process.

Firstly, in `muttrc`:

```bsh
macro index,pager S "| ~/.local/bin/file_email /tmp<enter>"
```

This pipes the full email (including headers and attachments) to the following script. Create an executable file at `~/.local/bin/file_email`.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Save piped email to "$1/YYMMDD SUBJECT.eml"

# Don't overwrite existing file
set -o noclobber

message=$(cat)

mail_date=$(<<<"$message" grep -oPm 1 '^Date: ?\K.*')
formatted_date=$(date -d"$mail_date" +%y%m%d)
# Get the first line of the subject, and change / to ∕ so it's not a subdirectory
subject=$(<<<"$message" grep -oPm 1 '^Subject: ?\K.*' | sed 's,/,∕,g')

if [[ $formatted_date == '' ]]; then
  echo Error: no date parsed
  exit 1
elif [[ $subject == '' ]]; then
  echo Warning: no subject found
fi

echo "${message}" > "$1/$formatted_date $subject.eml" && echo Email saved to "$1/$formatted_date $subject.eml"
```

This script saves the file to the first argument (i.e. in the `muttrc` example above, the email will save to `/tmp`). The format of the file name is `YYMMDD SUBJECT.eml`. It also converts `/` to `∕` to prevent creating subdirectories.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to use `formail` in the script?

Comment: @0andriy I'm not familiar with `formail`, so I had a read. However, I'm not entirely sure which part of my script you were referring to? Using `formail` to extract subject and date? If so, probably a nice idea. I'd urge you to write an answer; I'd definitely upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried all the suggested answers but could not get the raw, multipart (text/plain + text/html) e-mail to be saved to a file, including it's headers and everything. I needed this to feed my spam-filter with the e-mail to teach it, that a specific mail is spam or not...

The solution I came up with is pressing `e` (i.e. "edit message") on the open message, which opens the **raw message** in your editor of choice. Raw here means, that you get the message exactly as it arrived in mutt, so you have all the headers and all the bytes that comprise the message.

After hitting `e`, I just write the buffer (I set editor to *vim*) to a file with `:w <path_to_file>/<file_name>` and that's it.

P.S: I would have added this as comment but you need a certain level of reputation to do this. Also, I know the question is very old but as *neomutt* is still used by many people, I thought this might help someone.

**Update:** I overlooked the `pipe-decode` option that Kai was talking about. With that option set correctly it would have worked via `|`, too. Still my solution is working, too ;-)

Comment: Any solution if mailbox is read-only?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt You should go with the answer provided by Kai von Fintel. Don't forget the `set pipe_decode=yes` in your .muttrc however.