# Saving Pager-view as file in mutt? And open it in Vim?

Tags: vim, mutt

After following this post: [Saving email as file in mutt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60838/saving-email-as-file-in-mutt/98202), while in **Pager** view, pressing `v` and `s` in sequence will prompt the user to save the first attachment as a local file. As [commented in the solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60914/240390), there is no header info at all.

How to set up a macro that does the following?

1. Save the message with header info to a local file;
2. Use Vim to open such a file.

Also, I tried to *pipe* the message to Vim, by pressing `| vim<enter>` in **Pager** view. It does get the text to Vim, but that Vim session only stayed alive for seconds.

Comment: you could use `e` to and set EDITOR environmental variable to vim

Comment: @mrajner, thank you! How may I re-assign such action to another key? I tried `bind index,pager i edit`, but the new "mapping/binding" looks different from the native `e`'s mapping ==> the latter has been mapped to `edit   read`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're piping the message to vim you have to tell vim that it should read from /dev/stdout.

Try following:

```
| vim -<enter>
```

Comment: Piping through vim with the training `-` marker worked!